# How to convert data into DateTime object

Tags: c#, datetime, data-conversion

How do I convert a date string, in the general form of "ccyymmdd" in to a DateTime object in C#?

For example, how would I convert "20100715" in to a DateTime object.

Please - No RTFM links to Microsoft Tech Docs.

Many Thanks...

Comment: What does the "c" placeholder represent?

Comment: @jlafay the "c" represents century. Example: ccyy = 2010

Comment: Assuming you really mean 4 digit year, 2 digit month, and 2 digit day, you want `var dt = DateTime.Parse("20101231");` for the last day of this year.

Comment: -1 why should stackoverflow do your work for you if you're not willing to RTFM?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your prompt answers. Gotta say I was surprised how "ccyy" seemed to throw-off a few people. I've used that general form for many years because it helps me differentiate when dealing with legacy software that only supports date formats such as "dd-mm-yy". Sorry for any confusion it may have caused.

Comment: @Greg. You must have an unspeakable amount of spare time. Have you tried reading MS documentation on using C#? I'd love to have the time, but there are people out there who are happy to give a little of their time to save another's. That's what SO is for - isn't it?

Comment: I read "no RTFM links" as "no links to additional information so I can learn this for the next time I need to use it." I'm sorry if I misread that.

Comment: @logout It threw us off because I don't think that's standard. I always use "yyyy" to represent the full 4 digit year. "c" may work but won't be as recognizable by other developers so you may want to consider keeping "yyyy" instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
using System.Globalization;

DateTime.ParseExact("20100715", "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Of all the answers I think this is the cleanest way to parse the date string.

Comment: Spot on Mike. Thanks v much. Youv'e saved what little hair I have left.

Comment: No problem.  We follically challenged dudes need to stick together. :)

Comment: This is how I format my DateTimes too, and no sense answering the same solution. Good job Mike. +1

Answer (score 3):

`var dt = DateTime.Parse("your date string").ToString("yymmdd");`

I don't think `cc` is a valid date formatting option?

As Richard points out, you can also use `DateTime.ParseExact` which allows you to use culture information for the parsing, or you can use `DateTime.TryParseExact` which is the same as `DateTime.ParseExact`, but if there is an exception then a null date is returned rather then an exception being raised.

EDIT:

The question has been updated so that a `DateTime` is specifically returned. In that case you can omit the `.ToString()` part of my answer. Calling `DateTime.Parse()` will return a `DateTime` object. When getting the date value via `ToString()`, simply pass the required formatting string to get the date in the desired format.
Cheers.
Jas.

Comment: It means century. That's most (if not all) the OP is asking about.

Comment: Thanks Jason. Yes I know 'cc' is suspect, I just use it to help differentiate between century and year within century.

Comment: +1 but @Jason Evans you may want to edit your answer to keep it a datetime object instead of converting it back to a string. I think thats what @Noldorin was getting at.

Comment: @Noldorin - Fair enough, I've shown him how to parse dates in .NET, but not how to include a century value. I've +1 you since, fair play, you have provided a more thorough solution.

Comment: @Jason: That's very honorable. If you flesh out the bit about `cc` not being valid in the string... and remove the ToString call, I can change the -1 to a +1 though, my votes are never immutable. :)

Comment: This doesn't work.  DateTime.Parse() will not parse a string in the OP's stated date format.  DateTime.Parse("20100715") throws a FormatException.

Comment: Hah, I can't believe I've gone to much effort over nothing. `ccyy` is equivalent to `yyyy`, no rearranging necessary! Silly me.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx)

```
DateTime.Parse();
DateTime.ParseExact();
```

And worth a mention

```
DateTime.TryParse();
```

Answer (score 1):

If your date string is already sanitized (Borrowed from Mike's answer):

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("20100715", "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Otherwise:

```
DateTime dt;
if (!DateTime.TryParseExact("20100715", "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    // Handle bad date
}
```

Comment: it just means the 20 in 2010 (the OP means yyyymmdd)- a DateTime object will handle it just fine.

Comment: DateTime.Parse("20100715") throws System.FormatException.

Comment: He's changed it, it's ok now but it didnt work before. I removed my -1

Comment: I assume it was downvoted because it doesn't work.  See my earlier comment.

Comment: @Mike, you're right - I assumed it would work the same way as the SQL Server parser. The problem is more complicated than it first appears.

Comment: @w69rdy, I meant the ccmmddyy to represent the date string. Obviously confusing to everyone but me!

Comment: @Phil Yeah now you've changed it I can see what you meant!

Comment: @Phil. Well done (for not letting "ccyy" throw you). I've tried your TryParseExact() - works a treat. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

System.DateTime.Parse(yourDateString)

You might have to manipulate your string to a format that the method can handle first.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx

for more info

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the "cc" part is, but there are a few options.

[DateTime.Parse(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx) may be able to convert the string, but if the string is in a non-standard format you may have to do some pre-conversion first.

Comment: cc will be 19 for 19xx years and 20 for 20xx years.

Comment: So an example would be 19700101 for January 1st 1970?  That's almost certainly a non-standard string.  You could try DateTime.Parse, and if it doesn't work you'd have to rework the string and *then* feed the sanitized string into DateTime.Parse.

Comment: yyyyMMdd is about as standard as a date format gets. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Calendar_dates